# Многопоточный доступ к данным

Tags: c++, c++11

Один поток пишет в структуру, другие потоки читают. Требуется обеспечить транзакционность записи (т.е. чтобы при обновлении двух полей, потоки чтения не могли получить возможность прочитать наполовину обновленные данные).
В идеале для чтения иметь метод `const Foo& get() const;`.

В текущей реализации используется подход с мьютексами и хранением отдельных для каждого потока копий в std::map.

```
void ConfigUpdater::set(const Config& config)
{
    MutexGuard mutexGuard(mutex);
    this->config = config;
}

const Config& ConfigUpdater::get() const
{
    MutexGuard mutexGuard(mutex);
    return copies.emplace(boost::this_thread::get_id(), config).first->second;
}
```

Возможно есть лучшее решение, подскажите в какую строну копать.

Comment: Вместо мьютекса лучше использовать спинлок - если не нужна синхронизация между разными процессами, и если операция записи в поле - это тривиальное присваивание, а не копирование мегабайтов.

Comment: @gbg спинлок пожалуй здесь действительно будет уместнее, спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться `std::shared_lock<std::shared_timed_mutex>` для чтения и `std::unique_lock<std::shared_timed_mutex>` для записи, это позволить избежать копирования. `std::shared_timed_mutex` доступен в C++14, в C++17 есть `std::shared_mutex`.

Comment: `std::shared_mutex` практически идеально смотрится для моей задачи (позволит одновременно без блокировки иметь доступ на чтение).

Answer (score 6):

Если ваша структура *тривиально копируема*, оберните ее в [`std::atomic<>`](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic)

> Каждая специализация шаблона std::atomic определяет атомарный тип.
>   Только объекты атомарных С++ типов могут безопасно использоваться в
>   нескольких потоках одновременно. Когда один поток сохраняет данные в
>   объекте атомарного типа, а другой хочет их прочитать, поведение
>   программы определено стандартом.

```
#include <atomic>

//.........

struct Foo
{
    int alpha;
    char* beta;
};

using AFoo=std::atomic<Foo>;
```

Comment: Можно пример, как писать/читать `Foo`?

Comment: @VladimirGamalian наивно - раздаете потокам ссылку на нее, и они читают. За блокировки отвечает шаблон.

Comment: Не въеду, как это может работать. Или здесь только для каждого члена структуры отдельно атомарность гарантируется? Т.е. например обращаюсь в потоке чтения сначала к `alpha`, затем к `beta`, каким образом определяется, что это одна транзакция?

Comment: @VladimirGamalian а он вам так не даст, он только позволит получить копию структуры целиком. И вот это он сделает атомарно. А потом он также атомарно сможет целиком переписать структуру новой структурой.

Comment: А гарантирует ли std::atomic, что вид на память у всех читающих потоков будет одинаковым?

Comment: @VladD, что есть `вид на память`?

Comment: @alexolut,  что сквозь кэши и NUMA потоки увидят одно и то же.

Comment: @VladD там можно указать memory order, который и будет гарантирован.

Comment: @gbg: Круто, не знал. То есть это полноценный мини-mutex получается.

Comment: @gbg: Кстати, вы привели пример структуры, которая скорее всего _не_ является тривиально копируемой (из-за указателя).

Comment: @VladD ideone считает ее тривиально копируемой. http://ideone.com/8eA7uG

Comment: @gbg: Формально она такой и является. Но в реальности строку, на которую указывает указатель, в большинстве случаев неплохо бы бы склонировать при этом. (Поэтому я написал «скорее всего».)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41339/discussion-between-gbg-and-vladd).